# C++: Argument error while trying to call a function from a custom header file

Tags: c++, arrays, function, header-files

So, this program is meant to have three parallel arrays that carry the names of ten account holders, their IDs, and their balances. My main file looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "IOFunctions.h" // My header file
using namespace std;

int main ()
{   
    const int AR_SIZE = 10;

    string nameAr;
    int    idAr;
    float  balanceAr;

    // F U N C T I O N -- ReadInData
    ReadInData(nameAr,
               idAr,
               balanceAr,
               AR_SIZE);
}
```

The error I'm getting looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuNh7.png

Now, the header file looks like this:

```
#ifndef IOFUNCTIONS_H_ // This is my own header
#define IOFUNCTIONS_H_

#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


string ReadInData(string    nameArray[],
                  int       idArray[],
                  float     balanceArray[],
                  const int ARRAY_SIZE)
{
    ifstream inFile;

    string inFileName;
    string outFileName;

    // INPUT -- Prompts user for input file name
    cout << left << setw(40)
         << "What input file would you like to use? ";
    getline(cin, inFileName);

    // Checks that the file name entered is accessible
    while(inFileName != "InFile.txt")
    {
        cout << setw(40) << "Please enter a valid file name: ";
        getline(cin, inFileName);
    }

    // INPUT -- Prompts user for output file name
    cout << setw(40)
         << "What output file would you like to use? ";
    getline(cin, outFileName);

    // Checks that the file name entered is accurate to assignment
    while(outFileName != "OFile.txt")
    {
        cout << setw(40) << "Please enter a valid file name: ";
        getline(cin, outFileName);
    }

    // PROCESSING -- Takes the data from the input file and assigns it
    //               to the names array, ID array, and balance array

    // NAME ARRAY
    inFile.open(inFileName.c_str());
    for(int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index++)
    {
        inFile >> nameArray[index];
    }
    inFile.close();

    // ID ARRAY
    inFile.open(inFileName.c_str());
    for(int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index++)
    {
        inFile >> idArray[index];
    }
    inFile.close();

    // BALANCE ARRAY
    inFile.open(inFileName.c_str());
    for(int index = 0; index < ARRAY_SIZE; index++)
    {
        inFile >> balanceArray[index];
    }
    inFile.close();
    return outFileName;
}
#endif /* IOFUNCTIONS_H_ */
```

All help is greatly appreciated. If I'm missing anything, please let me know.

Comment: Have a look at that you are passing to the function, and what the function expects.

Comment: @juanchopanza I am and it looks fine to me. nameAr is a string, idAr is an int, balanceAr is a float, and AR_SIZE is a const int, just as the function expects. Am I wrong?

Comment: The function does not expect those types. The `[]` are not whitespace.

Comment: @user3517567 yes, `nameAr` is *one* string. It is not an array of strings, though. Likewise, `idAr` is *one* int, not an array of ints. You should probably re-read the introduction to arrays in your fine book.

Answer (score 0):

`ReadInData` takes a `string*`, but you are passing it a `string`. Fix this by passing a reference:

```
string ReadInData(string    &nameArray, //<--
              int       idArray[],
              float     balanceArray[],
              const int ARRAY_SIZE)
```

Comment: I thought arrays were automatically passed by reference?

Comment: Yes but you are not passing the function an array

Comment: I'm trying to. If I make the changes you suggested, will it become/stay an array?

Comment: `string` is **not** an array. It is an object. What do you want to pass to the function?

Comment: @user3517567 There are no arrays involved here. A `[]` in a function parameter list, confusingly, is a pointer. But you aren't even trying to pass arrays anyway.

Comment: nameAr, idAr, and balanceAr are what I want to be arrays, to point to the respective arguments in the function ReadInData. I want nameArray, idArray, and balanceArray all to be arrays.